# What happened to Packet.setProperty() in (a)Smack 4.0?

Tags: android, smack, asmack

Hi i am recently converting from aSmack 3.X to aSmack 4.0. In aSmack 4.0 it seems that the `Packet.setProperty()` method has been removed. Is there any documentation or examples of how to get this setting to the packet back in aSmack 4.0 as my system relies heavily on aSmack properties.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods where moved out of smack-core into smack-extensions with Smack 4. You now need to use [`JivePropertiesManager.getProperty(Packet, String)`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/jiveproperties/JivePropertiesManager.html#getProperty%28org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`JivePropertiesManager.addProperty(Packet, String)`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/jiveproperties/JivePropertiesManager.html#addProperty%28org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to add and get those.

More info about the API changes from Smack 3 to Smack 4 can be found at the official ["Smack 4.0 Readme and Upgrade Guide"](https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2703).

Comment: Ahhhhhh thank you so much. Have been pulling my hair out looking at documentation on smack 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an upgrade of my last FCM XMPP Connection Server application. Now, this project uses the latest version at this time of the Smack library (4.1.8).

https://github.com/carlosCharz/fcmxmppserverv2

This is my sample java project to showcase the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) XMPP Connection Server. This server sends data to a client app via the FCM CCS Server using the XMPP protocol.

https://github.com/carlosCharz/fcmxmppserver

And also I've created a video in youtube where I explain what the changes are.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVKEj6PeLTc

Hope you find it useful.

Here is a code snippet for the implementation:

```
    public class CcsClient implements StanzaListener {

    //Other code

    public void connect() throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException {
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setServiceName("FCM XMPP Client Connection Server");
    config.setHost(Util.FCM_SERVER);
    config.setPort(Util.FCM_PORT);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.ifpossible);
    config.setSendPresence(false);
    config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
    // Launch a window with info about packets sent and received
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(mDebuggable);

    // Create the connection
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

    // Connect
    connection.connect();

    // Enable automatic reconnection
    ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection).enableAutomaticReconnection();

    // Handle reconnection and connection errors
    connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection successful ...");
            // TODO: handle the reconnecting successful
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection failed: ", e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle the reconnection failed
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnecting in %d secs", seconds);
            // TODO: handle the reconnecting in
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection closed on error");
            // TODO: handle the connection closed on error
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection closed");
            // TODO: handle the connection closed
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "User authenticated");
            // TODO: handle the authentication
        }

        @Override
        public void connected(XMPPConnection arg0) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection established");
            // TODO: handle the connection
        }
    });

    // Handle incoming packets (the class implements the StanzaListener)
    connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(this,
            stanza -> stanza.hasExtension(Util.FCM_ELEMENT_NAME, Util.FCM_NAMESPACE));

    // Log all outgoing packets
    connection.addPacketInterceptor(stanza -> logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {}", stanza.toXML()), stanza -> true);

    connection.login(fcmServerUsername, mApiKey);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Logged in: " + fcmServerUsername);
}\
```

}